# How to call alert immediately after user write value out of range

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call alert immediately after user enter value out of range and not at submit button of form.

```
<input type="number" name="interest_rate" min="5" max="20" maxlength="2" onclick="box()" id="input2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Interest Rate" required>

    function box(){

    var check=parseInt((document.getElementById('input2').value));

    if((check<5) || (check>20))
        {
        alert("Please enter in range between 5 to 20");
        }

}
```

Comment: You can use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event

Comment: use `oninput=box()`.    This event is similar to the onchange event. The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this way with `onblur` or `oninput` event instead of `onclick` because using your number range **min=5** and **max=20**, it is not possible to call `alert()` with `onchange` or `onclick`

```js
function box() {

  var check = parseInt((document.getElementById('input2').value));

  if ((check < 5) || (check > 20)) {
    alert("Please enter in range between 5 to 20");
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="interest_rate" min="5" max="20" maxlength="2" oninput="box()" id="input2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Interest Rate" required>
```

Comment: @RohanKalyankar its because you're using `||` condition. so `check < 5` invokes your `alert()` here

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the onkeydown event listener

This listener will respond as soon as you start typing in

```
 <input type="number" name="interest_rate" min="5" max="20" maxlength="2" onkeydown="box()" id="input2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Interest Rate" required>


 <script>
    function box(){

       var check=parseInt((document.getElementById('input2').value));

       if((check<5) || (check>20)){
          alert("Please enter in range between 5 to 20");
       }
    }
 </script>
```